# How can I show UI hints for form controls like the Stack Overflow Career CV form does?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, user-interface

I'm trying to show some UI Hints on an ASP.NET MVC 2 app, much like the way they are displayed on the careers site when you edit/fill out your resume: when a form control has focus, a little description of how to enter the required information appears next to it.

[Example #1 http://shog9.com/so_careertip2.png](http://shog9.com/so_careertip2.png)
[Example #2 http://shog9.com/so_careertip1.png](http://shog9.com/so_careertip1.png)

What is the best method to show these suckers...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something in the line of:

**CSS:**

```
.field{position:relative;}
.field-help{display:none;background:yellow;position:absolute;left:200px;top:0;}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="field">
    <input type="text">
    <div class="field-help">Help text</div>
</div>
```

**JQUERY:**

```
$('.field input').bind('focus', function(e) {
    $(e.target).next('.field-help').show();
}).bind('blur', function(e) {
    $(e.target).next('.field-help').hide();
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Clean your ears!

Err, I mean use the jQuery Qtip plugin:
http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/

It does 100% of the things your looking for and does it extremely well.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery will simplify this, but it could easily be standard JS.

Something like:

```
$('.controlwithhinttext').focus(function() {
    // show hint
    $('#hint' + $(this).attr('hint_to_show_id')).show();
});
```

Where the form control has a custom attribute, or just use matching (not identical) IDs.

Comment: What do you mean by Matching IDs?

Comment: I meant to use the form control's ID as part of the selector.